# Unique constraint with column from parent table

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I have a table structure;

[image]

The ExternalArticle's are the different order numbers for all Article variations from a Relation.
ExternalArticle has column OrderCode which should be unique for all ExternalArticle's from a Relation.
But Relation is only present in parent table Article not in table ExternalArticle.

Now, how do i create unique constraint RelationId-OrderCode in ExternalArticle?

Do i have to insert a 'redundant' RelationId column in ExternalArticle fro this unique constraint?

Comment: Can you show us current and expected output with proper table structure?

Comment: yes, here it is

Comment: You currently could have ExternalArticle A from (actual, regarding to OrderCode) Relation 1 and ExternalArticle B from (actual, regarding to OrderCode) Relation 2 both assigned to Article X that you could assign to Relation 3. There is nothing in your datamodel stopping you from doing that. You will usually have that RelationId somewhere in ExternalArticle (also solving your problem), and map those to "your" articles (which would also e.g. allow you to buy Article "X" from supplier 1 or 2 based on conditions (price, availability, ...) and still sell it to your customers as the same Article X).